# Facebook chat API - XMPP typing paused notifications

Tags: facebook, xmpp, chat, typing

I'm using the XMPP protocol in order to send and receive messages with the Facebook chat.
I'm able to receive messages, and as well get the typing notifications.

My problem is that I'm not receiving the 'typing paused' notification.

My app has successfully made the auth procedure and when the user is typing a message I'm receiving the 'composing' message but when he stops typing I'm not getting the 'paused' message that is documented in the [XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) protocol.

Thanks

Comment: help me in getting typing notification..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is most likely that Facebook doesn't support `<paused/>`. Only support for `<active/>` and `<composing/>` is [absolutely required](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html#bizrules-support) by the XEP.

Your client should handle `<paused/>` appropriately, but also handle not receiving it just fine too.